# Specific form of an exponential function given two points and a slope

Tags: exponential-function

Given a general equation for an exponential function:
$$y=Aa^{-x}$$
I would like to find its specific form that would conform the conditions below:

[image]

- it starts from hight $y(0)=H$
- at distance $w$, its height is $h$ and slope $S=-0.1$

It's been long time I haven't touched math and I find quite difficult to solve this equation :/ I think, as the slope is involved, I must include a differential equation.

I have found a derivative of the function:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}Aa^{-x}=Aa^{-x}\ln(a)$$
Now, the set of differential equations is following:
$$\begin{cases} y=Aa^{-x} \\ \dot{y}=Aa^{-x}\ln{a} \end{cases}$$
I have worked out that $A=H$ given $y=0$.

For now onward I don't really know how to proceed. I don't know how to handle unknown $a$ in two forms $a^{-x}$ and $\ln{a}$. Any help is always appreciated :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Express the two remaining constraints:

- $y(w)=h=Ha^{-w}$,
- $y'(w)=S=-Ha^{-w}\ln(a)=-h\ln(a)$.

They give you two ways of computing $a$, namely

$$a=\sqrt[w]{\frac Hh}$$and $$a=e^{-S/h}.$$

Unless these two values coincide by chance, what you are asking is not possible (three constraints on two unknowns).